# How to loop through Vaadin buttons?

Tags: java, vaadin

I wanted to know is it possible to loop through all buttons in multiple files?
For example, let's say i have a few classes:
Class1.java

```
Button btn1 = New Button("BUTTON");  
Button btn2 = New Button("BUTTON");
```

Class2.java

```
Button btn3 = New Button("BUTTON");
```

I guess one way how to change each button's style would be like this:

```
btn1.addStyleName("button");
btn2.addStyleName("button");
btn3.addStyleName("button");
```

But i want to change specific button colors without using addStyleName. The reason is - i have a lot of buttons that have the same caption. Any ideas?

Comment: "is it possible to loop through all buttons in multiple files?" - Sure, if you're putting all the buttons into the same container.  Then you can loop through the container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your own button class:

```
class MyButton extends Button {

    public MyButton() {
        super();
        setCaption("BUTTON");
        addStyleName("button");
    }
}
```

Comment: This was what i was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I think your need is a kind of Util class which will return the button objects with same class name. And call this Util method wherever you need.

eg.

```
public static Button createButton{
    Button button = new Button();
    button.addStyleName("button");
    return button;
}
```

Comment: I took @sascha answer instead because it suits my case better.